# Multi session in PHP to get some data

Tags: php, session

I have a table with some fields, two of those are named "id" and "role".
"Id" is a primary key and "role" is field containing user types such as "admin" or "generaluser" for log-in with different purposes.

When user signs-in, the code actually queries data from database with `SELECT * FROM`, I create a session `$_SESSION['role']` to store data from field "role". How can I store data from "id" too for next uses? is it safe to create another session?

Comment: If you've solved the problem and one of the answers to your question helped, please mark that answer as accepted to help future visitors to SO see how to solve this same issue. It seems many of your questions have answers but have not been accepted. It's considered good practice to accept answers that help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can save multiple variables to the `$_SESSION` as an array. For more information, I'd suggest looking at the [PHP.net page on $_SESSION](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php).

I'd suggest writing the code as

```
$_SESSION['myVars'] = ['id' => $user_id, 'role' => $role];
```

And then get it back with

```
$myVars = $_SESSION['myVars'];
$role = $myVars['role'];
```

**HOWEVER** PHP has many authentication and credentialing systems available for major frameworks and as standalone systems. I'd suggest using one of these for user management rather than rolling your own. Not only is this easier for you, it will likely give a higher standard of protection to your users as passwords will be correctly encrypted.